# Non blocking read never returns

Tags: c, linux, nonblocking, file-descriptor, ubuntu-15.04

I am trying to do a non blocking read but the function never returns. Can someone suggest something? Here is my code to set nonblocking fd.

```
from_ap = open(FFS_GBEMU_OUT, O_RDWR|O_NONBLOCK);
if (from_ap < 0)
    return from_ap;
```

I have also tried this with similar results

```
from_ap = open(FFS_GBEMU_OUT, O_RDWR);
int status = fcntl(from_ap, F_SETFL, fcntl(from_ap, F_GETFL, 0) | O_NONBLOCK);

if (status == -1){
perror("calling fcntl");
```

Here is where I call my read function:

```
rsize = read(from_ap, cport_rbuf, ES1_MSG_SIZE);
if (rsize < 0) {
    printf("error %zd receiving from AP\n", rsize);
    return NULL;
}
```

I have also tried this with similar results:

```
fd_set readset;
struct timeval tv;
FD_ZERO(&readset);
FD_SET(from_ap, &readset);
tv.tv_sec = 0;
tv.tv_usec = 100;

result = select(from_ap+1, &readset, NULL, NULL, &tv);

if (result > 0 && FD_ISSET(from_ap, &readset)){
    printf("there was something to read\n");
    rsize=read(from_ap,cport_rbuf,ES1_MSG_SIZE);
}
```

The last message received is "there was something to read" and code does not progress further. What I am doing wrong? This is not a multithreaded program so no one can change flags but I have anyways confirmed them with printing back the flags before reading.

Comment: Nothing catches my eye. Can you create a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example program](/help/mcve) that exhibits the problem?

Comment: @JohnKugelman  wrote a file as you said and it works without a problem but this one does not work.

Comment: why do you add 1 to from_ap in the select(from_ap+1)?

Comment: if you now have a working minimal, complete file, then you almost there, you will have to carefully examine the differences

Answer (score 1):

Does the device support O_NONBLOCK?  This appears to be code from GitHub for [gbsim](https://github.com/projectara/gbsim/blob/master/functionfs.c).  Read up on gbsim, it's entirely possible the driver does not support non-blocking calls.

Comment: yes the code is from gbsim. I am using DUMMY_HCD to loop back from a gadget I will definitely look into that

Comment: i have tried though using select to read only when data available and use blocking read  hoping the code will not get stuck into a block ;still it get stuck any suggestion on that

Comment: If a device doesn't support non-blocking I/O then it is unlikely to support `select` either. They're more or less the same thing.

Comment: Anyone stumbles on this problem later "functionfs" doesnot implement NON_BLOCK for any other endpiont save "ep0". However AIO is implemented and can be used to have non blocking behavior.